# format code from ide ( VS2008)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, code-formatting

Every once in a while I will paste in some code and it will lose all its tabs and look pretty bad

I know that in the vs2008 xml viewer there is a button to format(indent) all the code to the correct hierarchy

Is there such a function or macro or shortcut key that i could apply this to a section of code (or to all the code in that window)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit Menu - then Advanced - then Format Selection (if you have it highlighted).

Shortcut Key is: Ctrl + E, F (for selection) and Ctrl + E, D (for document)

Answer (score 4):

Careful on the keyboard shortcuts, I think they are dependent upon the developer environment style settings, e.g. my format document is Ctrl+K, D

Answer (score 2):

Format document

```
( Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D )
```

Format selection

```
( Ctrl-K, Ctrl-F )
```

Answer (score 1):

Item #42 from  ["Pimp My IDE": 101 Visual Studio tips, tricks, and add-ins](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127112218/http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2008/05/12/122087.aspx) by Brian Schroer. Some of the other tips are pretty good too.